# ExtJS checkbox dependencies

Tags: extjs

I have checkboxes with dependencies on others, for instance:

When I uncheck 'Make customers' it also has to uncheck 'View customers'.

But then 'Edit customers' is not unchecked, even though it has a dependecy on 'View customers'.

How do I make this function recursive so it checks for dependencies on the other checkboxes aswell?

Comment: Not sure what you trying to tell us. I have two date fields which depend on each other, and had to be really careful with what I did, because when I changed one, the other one changed as well, which triggered a change to the first, and so on, until the browser froze. So what you want to achieve should be working out of the box...

Comment: When I uncheck 1 box, it checks if there are any other checkboxes with dependecies on it, if yes, it unchecks those aswell. But it's doesn't uncheck boxes with dependencies on _those_ checkboxes.

Comment: You may want to use something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain dependency list and manage check/uncheck behavior by listeners.

I have added small fiddle for you. Hope that will help.

I have implemented for uncheck scenario only.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/19ok